# C# - EntityFramework | Comparação da Base de Dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Comecei a utilizar o EF faz pouco tempo, então não tenho muito conhecimento sobre ele.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer uma comparação da minha classe com a base de dados, utilizando o EF.

Exemplo da comparação:

Classe de Funcionários possui os seguintes campos:

> Código, Nome, Cep, Telefone, Cidade.

Na base de dados na tabela Funcionários, possui os seguintes campos:

> Código, Nome, Cep, Telefone, Cidade, **Estado**

Eu queria uma rotina do Entity que comparasse minha classe de Funcionários com a tabela de Funcionários, e me retornasse quais os campos que o banco possui, e que minha classe não possui, e vice e versa (classe possui, banco não possui).

Vocês sabem se é possível fazer isso, ou se o EF somente cria a base de dados de acordo com o mapeamento que fiz na minha classe?

Answer (score 3):

Podemos utilizar 2 estratégias com o EF: *Code First* e *Database First*.

### Code-First

http://www.devmedia.com.br/entity-framework-code-first/29705

### Db-First

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx

Pelo que entendi você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação que já possui um banco de dados.

Nesse caso você pode utilizar o [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). Essa ferramenta possui uma opção para você usar de engenharia reversa, ou seja, a partir do bando de dados ela cria as classes já com os `DataAnnotations`.

Segue link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

Desculpe, não conheço nenhuma ferramenta que compara o banco de dados com as suas classes, mas acho que a solução proposta irá te ajudar.